# Flex box Vertical Navigation Issue

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I recently started dabbing in Flexbox and I am trying to create a page that has a vertical navigation area on the side. My issue is that my content is appear UNDER the navigation area. Not to the side of it. I want to know how I can use Flex box to have my content appear next to the navigation like in this page:

http://cocoonstudio.ph/

Here is my page so far:

https://jorgeg1105.github.io/JG-Photography/

Thanks for your help!

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}


/*--------------Side Navigation Styles--------------------*/

#sidenav {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width: 60px;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  border-right: 6px solid #766E6B;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#sidenav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#sidenav li:nth-child(1) {
  margin-bottom: 120px;
}

#sidenav li:nth-child(6) {
  margin-top: 195px;
}

#sidenav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
}

#sidenav a:visited {
  color: white;
}

#sidenav a:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}


/*-------------Header Styles-------------------------------*/

header {}


/*------------------Main Navigation-----------------------*/

#mainnav {}


/*--------------------Container Area------------------------*/

#container {}


/*-----------------------Footer Styles---------------------*/

footer {}


/*-------------------Flexbox-----------------------*/

.col {
  flex: 1;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<nav id="sidenav" class="row">
  <ul class>
    <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.pinterest.com/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<header>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div>
            <a href="#">
              <p>Gallery</p>
              <span>Our Work</span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div>
            <a href="#">
              <p>About</p>
              <span>J&amp;G Photography</span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div>
            <a href="#">
              <p>Questions</p>
              <span>Facts</span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <h1>J&amp;G Photography</h1>
      <h3><em>"Explore. Create. Inspire."</em></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div>
            <a href="#">
              <p>Rates</p>
              <span>Your Investment</span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div>
            <a href="#">
              <p>Contact</p>
              <span>Get In Touch</span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<!--Font Awesome-->
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/d579f311e9.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would make `body` the `flex` parent, remove the `fixed` positioning from the nav, then introduce a sibling to the navigation that will fill the rest of the page, set to `flex-grow: 1` (or `flex: 1 0 0` for short) and set `overflow-y: scroll` so the content area will scroll vertically.

I would also re-work the navigation a little. Set it to `justify-content: center` so the icons are centered in the middle of the nav, then use an `auto` `margin` value for the top/bottom links to push them to the edges of the nav. Also added a `min-height` to your `#sidenav ul` so that all of the icons are visible, and `overflow-y: auto` in case it overflows so you can scroll that menu on a super short screen.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

/*--------------Side Navigation Styles--------------------*/
#sidenav {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 6px solid #766E6B;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

#sidenav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 400px;
}

#sidenav ul li:first-child {
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
#sidenav ul li:last-child {
  margin-top: auto;
}

#sidenav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
}

#sidenav a:visited {
  color: white;
}

#sidenav a:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}

/*-------------Header Styles-------------------------------*/
header {
}

/*------------------Main Navigation-----------------------*/

#mainnav {
}

/*--------------------Container Area------------------------*/

#container {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

/*-----------------------Footer Styles---------------------*/

footer {
}

/*-------------------Flexbox-----------------------*/
.col {
  flex: 1;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>| J&amp;G |</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav id="sidenav" class="row">
    <ul class>
      <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.pinterest.com/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div id="container">
    <header>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <div>
                <a href="#">
                  <p>Gallery</p>
                  <span>Our Work</span>
                </a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div>
                <a href="#">
                  <p>About</p>
                  <span>J&amp;G Photography</span>
                </a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div>
                <a href="#">
                  <p>Questions</p>
                  <span>Facts</span>
                </a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <h1>J&amp;G Photography</h1>
          <h3><em>"Explore. Create. Inspire."</em></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <div>
                <a href="#">
                  <p>Rates</p>
                  <span>Your Investment</span>
                </a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div>
                <a href="#">
                  <p>Contact</p>
                  <span>Get In Touch</span>
                </a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <main>
      foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>
    </main>
  </div>

  <!--Font Awesome-->
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/d579f311e9.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I am going to try and dissect all the changes so that I understand them.

Comment: @Fate you're welcome :) feel free to ask questions if something doesn't make sense.

Comment: The Flex 100 is a little confusing to me. Why 100 and not just 1? Also the units vh and vw are confusing to me as well.

Comment: `flex: 1 0 0` is just short for `flex: flex-grow flex-shrink flex-basis`. By default those values are `auto` but last I checked, not all browsers handle `auto` the same. You could just do `flex-grow: 1` or `flex: 1` if you want. But I like to specify them all so I know they'll behave consistently across browsers. `vh` and `vw` are viewport units. `50vw` or `50vh` would be "50% of the viewport width (`vw`) or viewport height (`vh`)"